# Add media library items to Menus using the Customizer (via Media Manager not URL)

Tags: menus, uploads, media-library, theme-customizer

You can add links to files in the media library URL via the **Custom Links** panel of the **Customizer** but for clients this requires multiple steps including cutting and pasting a URL from the media library (from a box that is much smaller than the URL!) and it's not the best user experience.  I am surprised that

1. This isn't already part of WP Core
2. I couldn't find a plugin to handle this.

I have looked into the settings but cannot seem to figure this out.

- $wp_customize->add_section
- $wp_customize->add_setting
- $wp_customize->add_control

As my backend coding is not great I have mocked up a visual.

**N.B.** Someone else has added it to **[WordPress ideas here](https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/medias-attachments-in-appearance-menus#post-34739).  Votes appreciated.**

[image: WordPress Customizer design with a Media Library option for Nav Menus]